# Wpf Modern Ui Not Responding message in window header issue?

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

[image]
[image]

In above image i am using Wpf ModernUi template, while form is not responding the UI changes like normal wpf window. If any one knows how to fix this kindly share.

Comment: I am not using ModernUi template, but it looks to me that you sould use an async methods behind the scene, do you?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I cleared the problem by implementing background worker.